# Cant´t safely remove external hdd

Tags: external-hdd

Hi I have a new external hdd and when I want to remove it I can unmount it but if I want to use the "remove it safely" option it tells that is not possible and gives me this message:

Error detaching: helper exited with exit code 1: Detaching device /dev/sde
USB device: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2)
SYNCHRONIZE CACHE: synchronize cache(10): transport: Host_status=0x07 [DID_ERROR]
Driver_status=0x00 [DRIVER_OK, SUGGEST_OK]

FAILED: No such file or directory
(Continuing despite SYNCHRONIZE CACHE failure.)
STOP UNIT: start stop unit: transport: Host_status=0x07 [DID_ERROR]
Driver_status=0x00 [DRIVER_OK, SUGGEST_OK]

FAILED: No such file or directory

should I be worried or it isn´t a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking here where your drive is:
[image]